# Groups question about center

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $G$ is a group with elements $a$ and $b$ and that $axa^{-1}=bxb^{-1} \forall x \in G.$ How would I show that $b^{-1}a \in Z(G)?$

Comment: Do you mean that $axa^{-1} = bxb^{-1}$ for all elements $x$?

Comment: What are $h$ and $g$?

Comment: They are also elements of G and a, b are arbitrary.

Comment: But $a$ and $b$ are set in stone, you don't get to choose what $a$ is. What did you think setting $a=h^{-1}g$ accomplished anyway? How would it have related to $b^{-1}a\in Z(G)$?

Comment: To prove that $b^{-1}a$ is in the centre, you need to prove that it commutes with *every* element of $G$. You've shown that $a$ and $b$ commute, which is something different. I'm not sure how bringing in $h$ and $g$ is supposed to answer the question. The question is specifically about the elements $a$ and $b$ given to you in the problem, not about other elements that you select yourself. In any case, nothing you've written shows that $a$ is in the centre, only that it commutes with $b$.

Comment: Three people just did the whole problem for the OP. That's super lame.

Comment: @whacka OP asked how to do it, not for a hint of how to do it, so three of us answered how. Admittedly I don't know all the etiquette of math.stackexchange, but is it not okay to give answers here?

Comment: Why is it lame? The answers are there precisely because they are "answers"!

Comment: @graydad The original version had OP asking if the argument they gave was okay. Now OP has changed it to asking how they would show it, which newbies have presumably interpreted as "do the whole problem for me so you can get points." This question is ultra-basic and yet the OP is having trouble, so I feel nudging is better than depriving OP of a learning experience. We usually expect our OPs to think, work, put in effort - as OP was originally doing until a combo of criticism and full complete answers changed their mind about that. This is why we have a bad rep as a mindless homework factory!

Comment: @graydad Re: your deleted comment, you don't get to excuse encouraging mindlessness and discouraging effort and hands-on learning by speaking of "interpretations" and "doing what the OP asked for." There are a lot of times when I think full, thorough answers are in order, but this is certainly not one of them. Not to mention that "how would I show this" could be adeptly answered without giving away everything - like, "what does it mean for $b^{-1}a\in Z(G)$, can you write it using an equation involving a $\forall x$, can you relate that equation to the original one?"

Comment: @whacka "Ultra-basic" maybe for you. Seems condescending to think it is necessarily the same for OP. The original question had OP asking both how to do it and if their argument was okay. Admittedly, a better answer would have also addressed OP's argument.  As far as expecting our OP's to think, work, put in effort, I don't think that is a fair for us to expect of any given OP. It is certainly ideal, but unrealistic for everybody. If somebody is just out to get an answer, they will get it, whether or not it is on this website. If somebody is out to genuinely learn, they will work to do so.

Comment: The OP *was* putting in effort until discouraged. Certainly we have a right to expect effort, or at the very least see if we can inspire it before giving up. I am not expecting skill or experience or insight or cleverness. Anyway, there are times when showing off and gathering points is fun and healthy and I do this too, but I don't think it's a good idea during teachable moments like this. I prefer something more socratic, in which we allow the OP the opportunity to make their own discoveries with nudges and rhetorical questions. I remember how fun discovery was, vs. just getting HW done.

Comment: @whacka This is a point-based website and I am a tutor; I am interested in both teaching and points. I just go about things differently than you do. I agree with you 100% that the best case scenario is for everybody to figure it out themselves. It's a great feeling. When I come across a post where an OP asks for a hint, I assume they intend to figure it out for themselves and I respect their wishes. When I find a post where just an answer is asked for, I respect that too. You and I interpret things differently. I don't think I am wrong because your opinion differs from mine or vice versa.

Comment: @graydad I already addressed how you're jumping the gun from "how would I show this" to "do the whole problem for me." The presumptuous interpretation of yours was your *personal choice*, it was not something necessitated by the circumstances. It was also your choice to *not even try* to help the OP help themselves; you jumped straight into doing the whole thing for them, and by the sound of it you would do it again anytime the OP fails to specifically use a word like "hint" or "clue." You and many others could easily do better on this site, and you all choose not to.

Comment: @whacka Okay.. is there like a code of conduct manual for how to provide answers on math.stackexchange, or a website etiquette page? My experience here is completely different than yours. I am familiar with the rules of posting a question on here, but not so much with responding to questions I guess. I would like to do better on this website. I didn't make a stackexchange account for asking/answering questions with the sole purpose of "choosing" to not do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with $axa^{-1}=bxb^{-1} $, $\\$ $ax=bxb^{-1}a$, $b^{-1}ax=xb^{-1}a$.

So $b^{-1}a \in Z(G).$

Comment: +1 for answering question when OP asks for an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Proof: Let $g\in G$ where G is our group.

$$
\begin{align}
gb^{-1}a&=1(gb^{-1}a)\\
&=(b^{-1}b)(gb^{-1}a)\\
&=b^{-1}(bgb^{-1})a\\
&=b^{-1}(aga^{-1})a\\
&=b^{-1}ag(a^{-1}a)\\
&=b^{-1}ag
\end{align}
$$

Since g was arbitrary, we conclude $b^{-1}a\in Z(G)$.
Note that a common technique to prove these things is to insert identities into your equations so that you can get some cancellation elsewhere in the equation.

Comment: +1 for answering question when OP asks for an answer to the question

Comment: @graydad Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$axa^{-1}=bxb^{-1} \\ \implies axa^{-1}b = bxb^{-1}b \\ \implies ax(a^{-1}b)=bx(b^{-1}b) \\ \implies ax(a^{-1}b)=bx(e) \\ \implies a^{-1}ax(a^{-1}b)=a^{-1}bx \\ \implies (a^{-1}a)x(a^{-1}b)=(a^{-1}b)x \\ \implies (e)x(a^{-1}b)=(a^{-1}b)x \\ \implies x(a^{-1}b)=(a^{-1}b)x$$